# Create Entity bundles programmatically

Tags: entities

The [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module seems great, but it does not provide any API (I looked at the source). So I think that will be enough to use Drupal API and/or Entity API.

About this module: it provides a new entity type 'Paragraph' and field with same name. User can create via UI 'Paragraph types' (bundles) with fields and view display settings like node entity.

**My question**: What's the right way to define bundle type for this entity type with custom fields in a custom module?

I think I must create fields first, using [field_create_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) and [field_create_instance()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) in [hook_enable()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7). But what's next?

I must create bundle for paragraphs entity and attach created field, but I don't know how and any searches always send me to documentation about how programmatically create entity itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more easy way to do this: Use the module functions.

paragraphs.module contain these functions:

- [`paragraphs_bundle_save()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/paragraphs/tree/paragraphs.module?id=cd6ad37c7eea42b0af64a25b6d34a4d8a25267b3#n563)  to create and update bundles
- [`paragraphs_bundle_delete()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/paragraphs/tree/paragraphs.module?id=cd6ad37c7eea42b0af64a25b6d34a4d8a25267b3#n593) to remove bundles
- [`paragraphs_bundle_load()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/paragraphs/tree/paragraphs.module?id=cd6ad37c7eea42b0af64a25b6d34a4d8a25267b3#n528) to get the list of bundles or load a bundle

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function MYMODULE_install() {
  // Create new Bundle.
  $bundle = new stdClass();
  $bundle->name = 'Test Bundle'; // user friendly label
  $bundle->bundle = 'paragraphy_test'; // machine name
  $bundle->locked = 0;
  $status = paragraphs_bundle_save($bundle);
}
```

Comment: Is there a simple method for drupal 8?